# How to render jsx based on some condition using ternary operation in react?

Tags: reactjs

i want to render the jsx based on a condition using ternary operation in react.

What i am trying to do?

i have the code like below that works perfect.

```
return (
    {this.has_rendered() && this.items_loaded()
        ? <ChildComponent/>
        : <ChildComponent
            on_prev={null}/>}
)
```

Now i want to check for other condition if its !current_user then i want to pass another prop named "on_next" to ChildComponent.

```
{this.has_rendered() && this.items_loaded() && !current_user &&
    <ChildComponent/>}
{!this.has_rendered() && !this.items_loaded() && !current_user &&
    <ChildComponent on_prev={null}/>}
{this.has_rendered() && this.itemss_loaded() && current_user &&
    <ChildComponent
        on_next={somevalue}/>}
{!this.has_rendered() && !this.items_loaded() && current_user &&
                <NavigationContent
                    on_prev={null}
                    on_next={somevalue}/>}
```

The above code works but as you see there is repetition of code. how can i fix this with ternary operator. could someone help me with this.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nested ternary is a bad idea.
You should use variables in this case

```
let component = null;
if (this.has_rendered() && this.items_loaded()) {
  component = current_user? <ChildComponent/> : <ChildComponent on_prev={null}/>
} else {
  component = ...
}
```

Comment: thanks i have updated my question with code that works. but i want that to be simplified.

Answer (score 0):

If `on_prev` and `on_next` attributes can have values all the time, consider this approch:

```
return (
    { this.has_rendered() &&
      <ChildComponent
        on_prev={this.items_loaded() ? somevalue : null }
        on_next={current_user ? someanothervalue : null} />
    }
)
```